# How to pass return value of method to an object in JSF?

Tags: java, jsf, jsf-2

I am developing a comments section for an application using JSF.
At the moment I am passing the comment to the database and rendering it below the comment input using ajax.
I am now trying to store the date that the comment was posted on to the comment object in the database. For the comment text, I assign the value of the input box to the appropriate entity within the comment object. I have a method written that returns the current date and time, and when a user adds a comment, I want to call this method, set it's value and pass it to the database.
Here is my code currently. I can't figure out how to make this work for the date at the JSF end. Thanks for any help.

**JSF page :**

```
<table>
        <tr>
        <td><div class="white"><H2>Comments</H2></div>
        <h:inputTextarea rows="5" cols="55" id="comment"  class="inputbox" value="#{commentBean.comment.commentText}"
                    size="20" /></td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
            <td></td>

            <!-- CODE I NEED TO SET THE DATE AUTOMATICALLY TO commentBean.comment.commentDate -->

            <td><h:commandButton id="update"
                    action="#{commentBean.addComment(searchBean.companyId)}" class="myButton2" value="Add Comment">
                <f:ajax execute="@form" render=":results" />
                </h:commandButton></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
```

**CommentBean :**

```
    public String addComment(int contractorId) {
        factory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(PERSISTENCE_UNIT_NAME);
        EntityManager em = factory.createEntityManager();   
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        Query myQuery = em.createQuery("SELECT u FROM BusinessAccount u WHERE u.id=:id");
        myQuery.setParameter("id", contractorId);

        List<BusinessAccount> accounts=myQuery.getResultList();
        BusinessAccount account =accounts.get(0);

        comment.setBusinessAccount(account); //managing both sides
        account.getComments().add(comment); //managing both sides
        em.persist(comment);

        em.getTransaction().commit();
        em.close();
        comment.setCommentText(null);

        return "success";
    }


public String calculateCurrentDateTime() {


       DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm");     
       //get current date time with Calendar()
       Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
       String currentDate=dateFormat.format(cal.getTime()).toString();


return currentDate;

}
```

**Comment Object Class :**

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "comments")
public class Comment {

@Id
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
private int comment_id;

@Column(name = "comment_text")
private String commentText;

@Column(name = "date")
private String commentdate;


public String getCommentdate() {
    return commentdate;
}

public void setCommentdate(String commentdate) {
    this.commentdate = commentdate;
}

@ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
@JoinColumns({ @JoinColumn(name = "contractor_id", referencedColumnName="id") })
private BusinessAccount businessAccount;

public BusinessAccount getBusinessAccount() {
    if (businessAccount == null) {
        businessAccount = new BusinessAccount();
    }
    return businessAccount;
}

public void setBusinessAccount(BusinessAccount businessAccount) {
    this.businessAccount = businessAccount;
}

public int getComment_id() {
    return comment_id;
}

public void setComment_id(int comment_id) {
    this.comment_id = comment_id;
}

public String getCommentText() {
    return commentText;
}

public void setCommentText(String commentText) {
    this.commentText = commentText;
}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

While the `addComment(int )` is invoked when the user post a new comment, just call and use at the same time the method `calculateCurrentDateTime()` before persisting your comment object, something like this:

```
public String addComment(int contractorId) {
    ...
    comment.setCommentdate(calculateCurrentDateTime()); // setting the comment's date property before adding it to the account object and before persisting
    account.getComments().add(comment); //managing both sides
    em.persist(comment);
    ...
}
```